# Proving a Hermite polynomial equality

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, polynomials, exponential-function

For $$H_{k}(x)=\frac{(-1)^{k}}{\sqrt{k!}}\exp\left\{\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\}\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}\exp\left\{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\}$$

I want to prove $H'_{k}(x)=\sqrt{k}H_{k-1}(x)$.

So far I have $$\begin{aligned}
H'_{k}(x)&=x\frac{(-1)^{k}}{\sqrt{k!}}\exp\left\{\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\}\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}\exp\left\{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\}+\frac{(-1)^{k}}{\sqrt{k!}}\exp\left\{\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\}\frac{d^{k+1}}{dx^{k+1}}\exp\left\{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\} \\ &=x\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{\sqrt{k!}}\exp\left\{\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\}\frac{d^{k-1}}{dx^{k-1}}\left(x\exp\left\{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\}\right)+\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{\sqrt{k!}}\exp\left\{\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\}\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}\left(x\exp\left\{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\}\right)\\ &=x\sqrt{k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{\sqrt{(k-1)!}}\exp\left\{\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\}\frac{d^{k-1}}{dx^{k-1}}\left(x\exp\left\{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\}\right)+\sqrt{k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{\sqrt{(k-1)!}}\exp\left\{\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\}\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}\left(x\exp\left\{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\}\right)
\end{aligned}$$

I'm having trouble dealing with the initial $x$ and also with the derivatives.

Comment: You're trying to prove something that isn't true. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Properties

Comment: @TrialAndError Check Lemma 1.3.2 (ii) of 'Gaussian Measures' by Vladimir I. Bogachev. It also states that $H'_{k}(x)=xH_{k}(x)-\sqrt{k+1}H_{k+1}(x)$, which I proved.

Comment: What you stated in your comment is true. What you stated in the problem is false. I don't know if the problem statement is a typo, but it is false.

Comment: @TrialAndError Which problem statement specifically? Do you mean my definition of the Hermite polynomial; what I want to prove; or my working out so far?

Comment: Oops! I missed your normalization constants. That might be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to get at this is through the generating function.
\begin{align}
         \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-t)^n}{n!}\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}e^{-x^2/2}
           & = e^{-(x-t)^2/2} \\
       \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-t)^{n}}{n!}e^{x^{2}/2}\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}e^{-x^2/2} & =e^{x^{2}/2-(x-t)^2/2}=e^{xt-t^2} \\
        \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}H_{n}(x)& =e^{xt-t^2}
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
        \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}H_{n}'(x)
  & = \frac{d}{dx}e^{xt-t^2} = te^{xt-t^{2}} \\
  & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n!}}H_{n}(x) \\
  & = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{n}}{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}H_{n-1}(x) \\
  & = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}\sqrt{n}H_{n-1}(x).
\end{align}
So $H_{n}'(x)=\sqrt{n}H_{n-1}(x)$ for $n \ge 1$ and $H_{0}'(x)=0$.

For the other identity you mentioned, you can view $H_n$ as a differential operator acting on the constant function $1$:
\begin{align}
         H_n(x)&=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\left[e^{x^2/2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2/2}\right]1 \\
  &=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\left[e^{x^2/2}\frac{d}{dx}e^{-x^2/2}\right]^n1 \\
  &=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\left[\frac{d}{dx}-x\right]^n1
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
     H_{n}'(x)&=\left[\frac{d}{dx}-x\right]H_n(x)+xH_{n}(x) \\
              &=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}\left[\frac{d}{dx}-x\right]^{n+1}1+xH_{n}(x) \\
         &=-\sqrt{n+1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}\left[\frac{d}{dx}-x\right]^{n+1}1+xH_{n}(x) \\
         &=-\sqrt{n+1}H_{n+1}(x)+xH_{n}(x)
\end{align}
The generating function method will also work, but, in this case, nothing could be more transparent than the operator method, at least from my point of view. Now if you differentiate and use the first identity,
\begin{align}
          H_{n}''(x) & = -\sqrt{n+1}H_{n+1}'(x)+H_{n}(x)+xH_{n}'(x) \\
       &= -\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}H_{n}+H_{n}(x)+xH_{n}'(x) \\
       &= -nH_{n}(x)+xH_{n}'(x)
\end{align}
Hence,
$$
       H_{n}''(x)-xH_{n}'+nH_{n}=0.
$$

Comment: I think you meant $\frac{d}{dx}$ instead of $\frac{d}{dt}$ and after the 'therefore', how do you jump exactly from the first line to the second line? Incidentally, this generating function is also in Bogachev's book. And to conclude that $H'_{n}(x)=\sqrt{n}H_{n-1}(x)$, how do you deal with the extra $\frac{t^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}$, which you have leftover since one series starts at $n=1$ and the other at $n=0$?

Comment: @user3482534 : Thanks, I fixed the derivative issue. The $n=0$ term must be 0, which gives $H_{0}'(x)=0$, as expected.

Comment: Just a quick question, but if I wanted to prove $H''_{k}(x)-xH'_{k}(x)=-kH_{k}(x)$, would it be a good idea to use the generating function again or go for a more direct approach?

Comment: @user3482534 : I added more for you, just to give you a variety of techniques.